# Ethersjs Infura contract connection

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I am trying to integrate ethersjs with Infura from my react app. I see in Infura documentation at https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/send-a-transaction/send-a-transaction-2 they have mentioned to create .env file and add the following details

```
ETHEREUM_NETWORK = "sepolia"
INFURA_API_KEY = "<API-KEY>"
SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY = "<PRIVATE-KEY>"
```

Who is signer here? Whose private key should be used here?
In earlier version of ethersjs we would just use `provider.getSigner()` to get the signer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ethers 5.7 documentation](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/signer/)

> The most common Signers you will encounter are:
> Wallet, which is a class which knows its private key and can execute any operations with it
> JsonRpcSigner, which is connected to a JsonRpcProvider (or sub-class) and is acquired using getSigner

In [Infura's documentation](https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/send-a-transaction/send-a-transaction-2) you have the following code snippet:

```
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.SIGNER_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
```

`getSigner` returns

> Returns a JsonRpcSigner which is managed by this Ethereum node, at addressOrIndex. If no addressOrIndex is provided, the first account (account #0) is used.

and `Wallet` is used to

> The Wallet class inherits Signer and can sign transactions and messages using a private key as a standard Externally Owned Account (EOA).

Simply put, two different ways to have a signer for your transactions.